# Check which app is doing what

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

Is there any way to check which app is doing what in android, from my application.
I mean

- if any app is reading call logs
- if any app is reading msg
- if any app is reading data from server
- if any app is accessing gps,
- if any app is playing music

Please suggest any idea, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is check if an app has the permissions required to do each task. The following snippet retrieves the permissions for all installed Applications:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
   Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
   try {
      PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
      //Get Permissions
      String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;   
      if(requestedPermissions != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
         }
      }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Beyond that, just because an app has permission to do something doesn't mean it is doing that. Some permissions cover more than one use, and the app could be using one part of what it has access to.